# How much more time my random forest (RF) model takes after increasing the number of rows?

Tags: r, performance, random-forest

I can train a RF model in R using a set containing 10,000 rows and 30 columns in approximately 5 minutes in my PC (i7, 16MB). Given that same PC (and keeping everything else constant), is there a way to estimate how much longer will it take to train a RF model with 5 times more data? Can I generalize it for N times more data?

Comment: I would try several cases with different numbers of rows N and plot the required time as a function of N. This could allow to estimate the required time for larger values of N by extrapolation. Probably it would help to plot the data with a semi-log scale.

Comment: @RHertel thanks. I was also wondering if characters/numeric/integers/factors also play a role